# R Studio keeps crashing when I'm trying to merge multiple csv files into a data frame. How do I fix this?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, rstudio

I have 12 csv files that I need to merge for analysis project and their size ranges from 20mb to 120mb per file.

I attempted cutting down to only using the necessary columns by using fread() so it reads 6 columns instead of the total 11.

I've assigned each of them into a data frame as shown below.

However, at some point doing these manually, especially for using View() of the data frame that contains the 12 csv data, I keep getting crashed from R Studio probably due to the memory usage and the whole environment just resets and I have to do everything over again.

Is there a shorting and less ugly way to do this without crashing?

```
Packages <- c("dplyr", "janitor", "skimr", "readr", "lubridate","tidyverse","tidyr")
lapply(Packages, library, character.only = TRUE)
library("data.table")

td2105 <- fread("/cloud/project/Capstone Cyclistic Project/202105-divvy-tripdata.csv",
                  select = c("rideable_type", "started_at", "ended_at",
                             "start_station_name","end_station_name","member_casual"))

td2106 <- fread("/cloud/project/Capstone Cyclistic Project/202106-divvy-tripdata.csv",
                select = c("rideable_type", "started_at", "ended_at",
                           "start_station_name","end_station_name","member_casual"))

td2107 <- fread("/cloud/project/Capstone Cyclistic Project/202107-divvy-tripdata.csv",
                select = c("rideable_type", "started_at", "ended_at",
                           "start_station_name","end_station_name","member_casual"))

td2108 <- fread("/cloud/project/Capstone Cyclistic Project/202108-divvy-tripdata.csv",
                select = c("rideable_type", "started_at", "ended_at",
                           "start_station_name","end_station_name","member_casual"))

td2109 <- fread("/cloud/project/Capstone Cyclistic Project/202109-divvy-tripdata.csv",
                select = c("rideable_type", "started_at", "ended_at",
                           "start_station_name","end_station_name","member_casual"))

td2110 <- fread("/cloud/project/Capstone Cyclistic Project/202110-divvy-tripdata.csv",
                select = c("rideable_type", "started_at", "ended_at",
                           "start_station_name","end_station_name","member_casual"))

td2111 <- fread("/cloud/project/Capstone Cyclistic Project/202111-divvy-tripdata.csv",
                select = c("rideable_type", "started_at", "ended_at",
                           "start_station_name","end_station_name","member_casual"))

td2112 <- fread("/cloud/project/Capstone Cyclistic Project/202112-divvy-tripdata.csv",
                select = c("rideable_type", "started_at", "ended_at",
                           "start_station_name","end_station_name","member_casual"))

td2201 <- fread("/cloud/project/Capstone Cyclistic Project/202201-divvy-tripdata.csv",
                select = c("rideable_type", "started_at", "ended_at",
                           "start_station_name","end_station_name","member_casual"))

td2202 <- fread("/cloud/project/Capstone Cyclistic Project/202202-divvy-tripdata.csv",
                select = c("rideable_type", "started_at", "ended_at",
                           "start_station_name","end_station_name","member_casual"))

td2203 <- fread("/cloud/project/Capstone Cyclistic Project/202203-divvy-tripdata.csv",
                select = c("rideable_type", "started_at", "ended_at",
                           "start_station_name","end_station_name","member_casual"))

td2204 <- fread("/cloud/project/Capstone Cyclistic Project/202204-divvy-tripdata.csv",
                select = c("rideable_type", "started_at", "ended_at",
                           "start_station_name","end_station_name","member_casual"))

td_2105_to_2204 <- rbind(td2105,td2106,td2107,td2108,td2109,td2110,td2111,td2112,td2201,td2202,td2203,td2204)

View(td_2105_to_2204)
```

Comment: dedicated package vroom might help you out: https://vroom.r-lib.org/

Comment: @I_O Thank you for your suggestion. I've looked into your link and thought it would be the solution but somehow it's not working. I've followed the code as shown in the example as such: test <- fs::dir_ls(glob = "202*csv") and the only result that is returned is: test <- fs::dir_ls(glob = "202*csv") a 0x0 tibble for some reason... Should I make a new question asking about this?

Comment: That's fine: since you `<-` assign the results of you file listing to object `test` they're not printed to the console.  `test` contains the names of the files to be read, not their content. `vroom(files)` makes the magic happen ;-) https://vroom.r-lib.org/articles/vroom.html#reading-multiple-files